# \listoffigures causes following sections to nest in it in toc

Tags: table-of-contents

For some reason, the TOC has some items nested that I don't intend to be nested. In the attached image, you can see that List of Acronyms, Abstract, and Acknowledgements are nested under List of Tables in the TOC, and that is not what I intend. Here is the order in which I'm entering the commands in texmaker:

```
   \tableofcontents
   \listoffigures
   \listoftables
   
   \section*{List of Acronyms}
    \input{Acronyms.tex}
   \input{Abstract.tex}
   \newpage
   
    \newpage
   \section*{Acknowledgments}
   \input{Acknowledgments.tex}
```

[image]

This is perplexing me, and I don't know where to begin troubleshooting.

Comment: the list of figures formatting is entirely specified by the document class and any packages loaded so you have goven no information about how it is defined here, so it is hard to say what to change. Please always include a small but complete document that shows the problem

Comment: although I would guess that your list of figures and liat of tables are using `\chapter*` but the ones you added by hand are using `\section*`